# Python 2.7 convert 2d string array to float array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I read the following string on a .txt file

{{1,2,3,0},{4,5,6,7},{8,-1,9,0}}

using `lin = lin.strip()` to remove '\n'

Then I replaced { and } to [ and ] using

```
lin = lin.replace ("{", "[")

lin = lin.replace ("}", "]")
```

My goal is to convert lin into a float 2d array. So I did

```
my_matrix = np.array(lin, dtype=float)
```

but i got an error message: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: [[1,2,3,0],[1,1,1,2],[0,-1,3,9]]"

Removing the dtype, i get an string array. I already tried to multiply lin by 1.0, make a copy of lin using .astype(float), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what sort of float do you expect? do you want to get an array of floats? `[[1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0],[8.0,-1.0,9.0,0.0]]` or some sort of concatenation `1230.4567`?

Comment: probably your best bet is to use the JSON library:

    `import json;
    json.loads(filecontent)`

this should give you an array of integers, which you can do calculations with

Comment: @kamik423 i want an array of floats [[1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0],[8.0,-1.0,9.0,0.0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the `JSON` library to parse the contents of the file and then iterate through the arrays and converting each element into float. However an integer solution might already be enough for what you want. That one is much faster and shorter.

```
import json

fc = '{{1,2,3,0},{4,5,6,7},{8,-1,9,0}}'

a = json.loads(fc.replace('{','[').replace('}',']'))

print(a) # a is now array of integers. this might be enough

for linenumber, linecontent in enumerate(a):
    for elementnumber, element in enumerate(linecontent):
        a[linenumber][elementnumber] = float(element)

print(a) # a is now array of floats
```

Shorter solution

```
import json

fc = '{{1,2,3,0},{4,5,6,7},{8,-1,9,0}}'

a = json.loads(fc.replace('{','[').replace('}',']'))

print(a) # a is now array of integers. this might be enough

a = [[float(c) for c in b] for b in a]

print(a) # a is now array of floats
```

(works for both python 2 and 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

readStr = "{{1,2,3,0},{4,5,6,7},{8,-1,9,0}}"
readStr = readStr[2:-2]
# Originally read string is now -> "1,2,3,0},{4,5,6,7},{8,-1,9,0"

line = readStr.split("},{")
# line is now a list object -> ["1,2,3,0", "4,5,6,7", "8,-1,9,0"]

array = []
temp = []
# Now we iterate through 'line', convert each element into a list, and
#     then append said list to 'array' on each iteration of 'line'
for string in line:
    num_array = string.split(',')
    for num in num_array:
        temp.append(num)
    array.append(temp)
    temp = []

# Now with 'array' -> [[1,2,3,0], [4,5,6,7], [8,-1,9,0]]
my_matrix = np.array(array, dtype = float)

# my_matrix = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]
#              [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0] 
#              [8.0, -1.0, 9.0, 0.0]]
```

Although this may not be the most elegant solution, I think it is easy to follow and gives you exactly what you're looking for.